# How to install a specific version of Redis using command in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, redis, terminal

Is there any way to specify the version while installing through the terminal? I specifically want Redis version 3.2.5 for a certain project.

I tried

```
sudo apt install redis
```

but it does not give control over the version.

Comment: `sudo apt install redis=version` though you'll probably have to specify an exact package version, like `3.2.5-1` or `3.2.5-0someppa1`. The current Ubuntu package is `5:5.0.7-2ubuntu0.1` so you probably need to find a backport of that specific old version from a third-party PPA.

Comment: ... Or compile from source from https://download.redis.io/releases/